# Redirect 301 files from subcategory to root

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I moved my prestashop from `subcategory(/shop)` to root and now,

to fix the 404 Not Found Errors, I have to redirect all pages

from

`"example.com/shop"`

to

`"example.com"`

(for example from `"example.com/shop/skirt"` to `"example.com/skirt"`). What do I have to add to .`htaccess`? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `Redirect` in your htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 /shop/ http://example.com/
```

This will 301 redirect your subfolder to the root including all pages and directories from `/shop` to `/` .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect

```
"example.com/shop/product-A"
```

to

```
"example.com/product-A"
```

try with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser so that the new URL appears in the location bar, add an R flag in square brackets:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```